# Bibtex wrongly compiles accent mark

Tags: latex, bibtex, accent-sensitive

I am attempting to compile my latex file and I have a source with author's last name with an accent mark (two dots above the letter o).  In the preamble of my file, I have

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{algpseudocode, algorithm}
\usepackage{url, hyperref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Then, at the end of the file, I have

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}
```

In the .bib file I have

```
@phdthesis{kon,
    author = {K\"{o}n},
    title = {TITLE}
    year = {2014}
}
```

However, when I compile (I'm using TeXStudio), I get what you see in the image.

[image: what I see from the pdf file]

It doesn't seem to be recognizing that there are two quotes (' is highlighted in blue and then ' is highlighted in black in the IDE I'm using).  I'm not sure how to get the correct accent mark.  I can't seem to find this issue elsewhere, and there are no other ways in latex literature (that I can find).  Thank you!

Code for .tex file:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{jmlr2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{algpseudocode, algorithm}
\usepackage{url, hyperref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
    Here is how it gets cited: \citep{konig2014}
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibl}
\end{document}
```

Code for .bib file:

```
@phdthesis{konig2014,
    author = {K\''{o}nig, R.},
    title = {Enhancing genetic programming for predictive modeling},
    school = {\''{O}rebro University},
    year = {2014}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's `\"` (backslash, double quote) and not `\''` (backslash, single quote, single quote)?

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]? If I puzzle together your code fragments and guess the missing pieces, it works fine....

Comment: @Thomas: yes.  In my IDE, they result in the same three characters.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I added all the code for an m.r.e..  It still doesn't compile correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since your edit, your `.bib` file shows `\''` (backslash, single quote, single quote), which is *wrong* and results in the weird accents you're seeing: it's putting an acute accent (`´`, coded as `\'`) on top of a single quote (`'`, also coded as `'`). The correct syntax is `\"` (backslash, double quote).

Answer (score 0):

If I write the `.bib` file in the program TeXworks, then `\"` (backslash, double quotes) automatically turns into `\''` (backslash, single quote, single quote).  Even if I compile my `.tex` file that references the `.bib` file in TeXstudio, I still get weird symbols as show in the image above, rather than the expected two dots above the o because TeXworks doesn't seem to recognize the double quotes.  BUT if I write the `.bib` file in the TeXstudio program, then it compiles as expected.  I'm not sure what's going on behind the scenes (maybe there is a setting I have to change?), but the issue was TeXworks, not the `\"{o}`.

Thanks all for your help!